# Is there a real-time inline field validation module?

Tags: forms

Currently I'm using the [Clientside Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module for field validation, but I want to have per field real-time validation, like a check thingy showing if it's correct or a small inline error when there's an error in there. I searched a bit and I couldn't find a proper module.

Is there a module for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [RichForm](https://www.drupal.org/project/richform) ?

> **The module has two actions:**
>
> Validation: The validation has a client-side and a server-side
>   routine.The first one is linked to the onChange JavaScript event:
>   after the user modifies the selected field, the validation action is
>   triggered. If there is any error, inline feedback is provided. There
>   is another client-side routine, which is triggered after clicking on
>   the submit button. If there is no error, the server-side validation
>   routine is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

[Inline Form Errors](https://www.drupal.org/project/ife)
I thinks it is better for you

> IFE or Inline Form Errors allows you to place form submission error
>   inline with the form elements. Three options are provided for setting
>   your inline error behaviour. You can configure the default behaviour
>   or override the behaviour on a per form basis. You can add as many
>   forms as you like.
>
> IFE provides three behaviours for the configured forms
>
> Leave the messages in place, this option will copy the error messages
>   and place them inline. The original error messages set by Drupal will
>   remain in place Show an alternative message, this option will replace
>   the original messages with a generic error message such as 'Please
>   correct all errors.'. This message can be set in the IFE configuration
>   page. The original error messages are placed inline with the form
>   elements Remove all messages, this option will remove all error
>   messages and place them inline with the form element In all cases only
>   the messages related to the form will be touched. All other messages
>   will remain in tact.

Comment: there's no real-time clientside validation with this module, but thanks

Comment: Also it is very old and no longer maintained as it seems.